# How to display array as a list in a table Angular

Tags: c#, html, css, angular, html-table

I have a list that contains 1 element which looks like this

[picture of array and contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbmVU.png)

I want to display the data in a table with the headers being Author Name and Title. But the code I have shows all the titles on one row instead of creating more rows for each Title and Author Name. How can I achieve this?

[Table I have with the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FxZu.png)

```
<table class='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tableLabel" *ngIf="authorWithBooks">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Author Name</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let authorWithBook of authorWithBooks">
      <td>{{ authorWithBook.authorName }}</td>
      <td>{{ authorWithBook.bookNameList }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need two loops: 1 for each author and 2nd one for each book title. The `tr`s will be created from the second loop. The first loop doesn't need to create any HTML, so it will go into an `<ng-container>` element.

This:

```hmtl
   <ng-container *ngFor="let authorWithBook of authorWithBooks">
    <tr *ngFor="let bookName of authorWithBook.bookNameList">
      <td>{{ authorWithBook.authorName }}</td>
      <td>{{ bookName }}</td>
    </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

And here is the working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4nbmj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)